# Change Value of Class Instance Property inside Dictionary of Lists of Class Instances

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a variable of type `Dictionary<int, List<MyType>>` where MyType is a class with several properties and methods. I am showing only two properties and no methods as they are irrelevant to the question.

```
class MyType
{
    private string property1;
    private double property2;

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return property1; }
        set { property1 = value; }
    }

    public double Property2
    {
        get { return property2; }
        set { property2 = value; }
    }
```

I would like to iterate over the dictionary and find all class instances for which a property (say for example Property2) of the class instance has a specific value.

Once I have this, I would like to modify the value of the property and perform additional calculations.

I have been looking how to do this but cannot seem to find anything that helps. I have looked at the `.ToLookup()` method but I am not sure how to use it in this context. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need the key values of the dictionary for whatever your calculations are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over a dictionary you use the [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  Since you have a list as your value you need to nest a loop within the iteration of the dictionary.  Here's an example assuming `myDictionary` is of `Dictionary<int, List<MyType>>`:

```
foreach(var keypair in myDictionary)
{
     foreach(MyClass m in keypair.Value.Where(v => v.Property1.Equals("something"))
     {
          //do whatever you want here with m being an object in the list of MyClass
     }
 }
```

The LINQ [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) statement takes a lambda where whenever the lambda would return true, those objects will be part of the list's iteration.

If you just want an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` from the internal list and you don't care about the keys you can do this:

```
var iterableMyClass = myDictionary.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value)
                                  .Where(v => v.Property2.Equals("something"));
```

Now `iterableMyClass` is a single `IEnumerable<MyClass>` object that combined all of the lists within the dictionary.  This is because [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to 'flatten' multiple collections.  The Where operation also filters the returned `IEnumerable` in the same way as it does within the `foreach` loop in my first example.

Using this single IEnumerable, you can then use a simple `foreach(MyClass m in iterableMyClass)` to iterate over all of the objects that matched.

**EDIT**

Per our discussion below if you need to get a count or tell if the IEnumerable contains at least one item you can do either of the following.

To get a count of matches you can just call `.Count()` on the IEnumerable object, but if you don't actually need the objects at all you can just do this:

```
var count = myDictionary.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value).Count(v => v.Property2.Equals("something");
```

To get a boolean determining if there is at least one match, but don't need the objects that matched:

```
bool atLeastOne = myDictionary.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value).Any(v => v.Property2.Equals("something");
```

Comment: I never thought about it until you mentioned it, but I do like the IEnumerable approach. Would the variable iterableMyClass be a list of all the class instances in the dictionary that meet my criteria regarding Property2?

Comment: @PBrenek Yup.  It essentially merges all of the lists in the dictionary into a single IEnumerable and then filter so only the matching values are within this IEnumerable.  You can essentially treat an IEnumerable as List that you cannot edit.

Comment: Thank you. One additional item I wanted to ask. Is there a way to get a count of the number of items in the IEnumerable? Actually I only need to know whether there are any entries or none. Thank you. I think iterableMyClass.Any() should do the trick, no?

Comment: @PBenek Absolutely!  Let me edit my answer to show you what you can do regarding that

Comment: @PBrenek Just updated to give you a few options on how to do it.  LINQ is super powerful once you get the hang of it

Comment: Thank you, that is excellent information. I actually need the iterableMyClass. I just need to know if the iterableMyClass is empty, or has entries. I think I can use iterableMyClass.Any() to do that. Is that correct? I would not want to do the boolean for determining if there are any matches and then follow it up with the actual creation of the IEnumerable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80426/discussion-between-jnyranger-and-pbrenek).

Answer (score 3):

You could use two foreach loops and the LINQ `.Where` extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<MyType>> kv in dict)
{
    foreach (MyType t in kv.Value.Where(v => v.Property2 == 2.0))
    {
        // Use t for further calculations
    }
}
```

If you want a LINQ-less solution, you might use an if statement inside the inner loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<MyType>> kv in dict)
{
    foreach (MyType t in kv.Value)
    {
        if (t.Property2 != 2.0) continue;
        // Use t for further calculations
    }
}
```